# Что такое ArrayList<> в Java

Tags: java

Одно из условий задачи: 
В классе `Cat` добавь `public` статическую переменную `cats (ArrayList<Cat>)`.
Я это понимаю вот так:

```
public static int cats;
```

Вопрос: Что за `(ArrayList<Cat>)`?

Comment: Почитайте про generic. Вот официальная документация https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Изложите пожалуйста подробнее в описании вопроса условие задачи. Откуда вы взяли ArrayList<Cat>?

Comment: Если бы мне такую задачу поставили с таким условием, то я бы понял так: `public static ArrayList<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();`. Или так `public static List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();` При чём тут `int` вообще?

Comment: @МихаилРебров, вот собственно условие задачи:/* Статические коты
1. В классе Cat добавь public статическую переменную cats (ArrayList<Cat>).
2. Пусть при каждом создании кота (нового объекта Cat) в переменную cats добавляется этот новый кот.
   Создать 10 объектов Cat.
3. Метод printCats должен выводить всех котов на экран. Нужно использовать переменную cats.
*/

Answer (score 10):

```
ArrayList<Cat> - это список, в котором лежат объекты класса Cat
```

ArrayList - это одна из реализаций интерфейса List(список) за основу которой берётся обычный массив.

Существуют и другие реализации этого интерфейса: например LinkedList(Связанный список).

Изучите подробнее тему коллекций в Джаве.

- http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-Collections
- http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/collections.php
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/237043/
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/162017/

Про Дженерики Вам написали, в комментарии.

Answer (score 10):

Представь массив, который ведет себя как объект. Т. е. у него есть методы, которые позволяют добавлять/удалять в себя что-то. Вот такой хитрый массив и называется `ArrayList`.
Чтобы ты мог добавлять в `ArrayList` только `Сat`, ты сам себя ограничиваешь:

```
ArrayList<Сat>
```

При такой конструкции в `ArrayList` невозможно ничего положить кроме экземпляров класса `Сat`.
Например, ограничить `String`:

```
ArrayList<String>
```

Ничего кроме строк не положишь.